# magento add product with selectable dropddown field

Tags: product

I want user selectable drop down attribute .

**below is my case** 
i want to create product say shirt of different size s,m,l,xl. where user can select any of size and add it to cart .

As price of all shirts will be same so i do not want to create configurable project , then how can i do it please guide me i checked magento doc there does not seem any option to do that

there is custom option in add product form where it can be done but issue i that i will be using that product in bundled project also as far as i know magento does not allows products with custom option in bundled products.

how can i do it please guide me way for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am not sure what is your particular reason of not wanting to create config item.*

You should create configurable products. Looking at your requirement, magento config product feature actually address that.

The beauty of creating config product is, you can change price of any size if you want to and also those products can be used in bundle product with ease.

Comment: yeah as i said price of all will be same so no need of config products , i am using bundled product are there are sets of products that usually people buys like table+chair , etc

Comment: without having individual item, you cannot create bundle item in Magento. Also you can obviously duplicate the item to save time if data are pretty much same.